# Three column layout breaks on adding d3js chart

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to create a three column layout with a header and footer. I started adding divs to my first and second columns. Built the page for first two columns. Everything looked great. But as soon as I add `D3.js` chart using `dimplejs` to my third column, my layout breaks. Not sure what does it do to break the other two columns.

Working Layout looks like:
[image]

When I add the chart, the layout breaks. 
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcWp7.jpg

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgbhfpbz/) for explain what issue i am seeing.

You can consider me a newbie to d3js/dimplejs. I tried to investigate the layout, the divs and classes but couldn't figure out what am I missing. I noticed that the chart container seems to be somehow truncating too, as the y axis is not completely visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `vertical-align: top;` to `.column`

Answer (score 0):

As @Temani Afif mentioned, I added `vertical-align: top` to my class `.column` and everything just magically worked.

Here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgbhfpbz/3/).